# Change decimals for proportion of variance displayed in autoplot PCA

Tags: r, pca, axis-labels, prcomp, autoplot

I would like to change the number of decimals for the `Proportion of Variance` displayed in the axes of a PCA plot using `prcomp()` and `autoplot()`. By default it's set to 2 decimals places (92.46%, 5.31%) but I'd like to round them to 1 decimal place (92.5%, 5.3%).

> ```
> library(ggfortify)
> df <- iris[1:4]
> pca <- prcomp(df)
> autoplot(pca)
> ```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, disable the default variance percentage displayed by using:

```
autoplot(pca, variance_percentage = FALSE)
```

Then add the labels you want using:

```
autoplot(pca, variance_percentage = FALSE) +
  xlab("PC1 (%)")
```